# Letting implicit derived class constructor call base class constructor

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

```
public abstract class A {
  public A() {
    // do stuff
  }
}

public class B : A {
  // let implicit constructor of class B also call base()
}
```

I want my derived class' implicit constructor to call base(). How do I accomplish this in c# without making an explicit constructor for the derived class B?

Comment: but .... it already does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It already does; let's [run your code through sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANgHwAEBmAAgENgBnDKcsDUwgJlIEFSBvAWAChSmZNgAoAlFz4CBAemmkAJhFI0ArgDM1k0gF8+u3nxJNWAIVIh2E/qVmlcMRtgC2AB1zYw2RpAB2NKCoM0KQQasakZuS4VEpgUbikwORUMGJ6QA=) and look at the IL for `B`:

```
.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit B
    extends A
{
    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2058
        // Code size 7 (0x7)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: call instance void A::.ctor()
        IL_0006: ret
    } // end of method B::.ctor

} // end of class B
```

we can see here that `B` has a public parameterless constructor that calls `A`'s parameterless constructor (on `IL_0001`). Essentially,

```cs
public class B : A {
}
```

is short-hand for

```cs
public class B : A {
  public B() : base() {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It always implicitly calls constructor of base class. You can check it:

```
public abstract class A {
  public A() {
      Console.WriteLine("Class A");
  }
}

public class B : A {

}
```